# Empty space bottom of the screen

Tags: android, xml, android-framelayout

I am designing a layout for my app and i used a `FrameLayout` which is fairly simple,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/menu_slide"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000">

</FrameLayout>
```

This is my activity code,

```
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.SlidingMenu;
import com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.app.SlidingActivity;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

import codopoliz.com.hscomply.Fragments.SlidingMenuFragment;
import codopoliz.com.hscomply.Models.MenuModel;
import codopoliz.com.hscomply.R;

public class MainActivity extends SlidingActivity {

    private ArrayList<String> menuList;
    private MenuModel[] menuItems;
    private View mCustomView;
    private TextView title;
    private SlidingMenu sm;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sliding);

        setStatusBarColorInMain();
        setBehindView();
        setupDrawer();

        final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        mCustomView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_actionbar, null);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setElevation(0);
        ActionBar.LayoutParams layoutParams = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        actionBar.setCustomView(mCustomView, layoutParams);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        Toolbar parent = (Toolbar) mCustomView.getParent();
        parent.setContentInsetsAbsolute(0, 0);

        title = (TextView) mCustomView.findViewById(R.id.header_title);
        ImageView menubtn = (ImageView) mCustomView.findViewById(R.id.menu_Button);

        menubtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                sm.toggle();
            }
        });

        menuList = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("menu");
        Object[] arrayObject = (Object[]) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("menuItems");
        menuItems = Arrays.copyOf(arrayObject , arrayObject.length, MenuModel[].class);
        Toast.makeText(this, "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private void setBehindView() {
        setBehindContentView(R.layout.menu_slide);
        transactionFragments(SlidingMenuFragment.newInstance(), false, R.id.menu_slide, false, "MainFragment");
    }

    public void setActionBarTitle(String actionBarTitle) {
        title.setText(actionBarTitle);
    }

    public void transactionFragments(Fragment fragment, boolean backStackTag, int viewResource, boolean toogleOff, String fragmentTag) {
        final Fragment selectedFrag = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(fragmentTag);

        SlidingMenuFragment fragmentMenu = (SlidingMenuFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("MainFragment");
        if (selectedFrag != null && selectedFrag.isVisible()) {
            toggle();
            return;
        }
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(viewResource, fragment, fragmentTag);
        if (backStackTag)
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();
        if (!toogleOff) {
            toggle();
        }
    }

    private void setupDrawer() {
        sm = getSlidingMenu();
        sm.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
        sm.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
        sm.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
    }

//    @Override
//    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
//        switch (item.getItemId()) {
//            case android.R.id.home:
//                mSlidingMenu.toggle();
//                return true;
//            default:
//                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
//        }
//    }
//
//    @Override
//    public void onBackPressed() {
//        if (mSlidingMenu.isMenuShowing()) {
//            mSlidingMenu.toggle();
//        } else {
//            super.onBackPressed();
//        }
//    }

    public ArrayList<String> getMenuListData() {
        return menuList;
    }

    public MenuModel[] getMenuItemsData() {
        return menuItems;
    }

    public void setStatusBarColorInMain(){
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            Window window = this.getWindow();
            window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
            window.setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.color_status_in_main));
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my Style,

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <!--<item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>-->
        <!--<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>-->
        <!--<item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>-->
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppThemeSuper" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>

    </style>

    <!--For progress dialog-->
    <style name="AppCompatAlertDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/menu_white</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/menu_white</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Now i tested in multiples devices in most of them the design works fine. It is like this,

[image]

But in some devices there is a white empty area appearing at bottom of the screen. Like this,

[image]

I also checked by rotating the device and the white area appears at right side of the screen.

How can i remove this empty space from the screen. Please any help would be appreciated..

Comment: Can you include the full XML for your layout?

Comment: Put your complete xml file then we can help you better

Comment: and use `match_parent` insteadof `fill_parent`

Comment: and don't mix `fill_parent` and `match_parent`. Use match only

Comment: Is this on an physical device or on the emulator? Can you give the model of an example device? Does the white area show the navigation  buttons (triangle, circle, and square)?

Comment: Hi, I used match_parent but it is not working. These screenshots are from a physical device i have not tried it on emulator.

Comment: @UltimateDevil This is the complete xml file there is nothing on this screen. other than this i have a custom actionbar which is in top in pink color...

Comment: can you tell me which device you are using @Proloy

Comment: @UltimateDevil I used devices like Asus Zenfone 2, Redmi Note 3 etc and the design appears fine in those. In Lennovo A7700 the empty space persists.

Comment: please try to change `FrameLayout` to `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout` for testing only and see they also behaves like `FrameLayout` to that device

Comment: @UltimateDevil Not working...one thing i should mention I am using a SlidingMenu on click of that menu button on left of actionbar. I using this library [link](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu). is it because of that anyhow?

Comment: Post your styles and the activity code

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos i edited the question with my activity code and style.

Comment: Your SlidindMenu is white and is always visible. doesnt know how to fix sorry

Comment: But, if you looking for a native solution we may help better

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos Yes Please any kind of solution would good for me..

Comment: In  your case, you are seeing the second Fragment that you are adding to the bottom, the one that is expandable

Answer (score 1):

add this flag after setting status bar color

```
 addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS)
```

It worked for me.